# How to delete tarfileset after creation of archive?

Tags: ant, tar, fileset

I have following ant target to create an archive of log files.

It collects all log files from the `.metadata` directory of an eclipse workspace recursively and log files from the project directories non-recursively.

I would like to delete the files after they have been archived. How can I achieve this?
I cannot use `fileset` as I need the extra attributes of the `tarfileset`.

```
<target name="tar_logfiles">
    <tar destfile="logs.tgz" compression="gzip">
         <tarfileset dir=".metadata" preserveLeadingSlashes="true" prefix=".metadata">
                <include name="**/.log*" />
                <include name="**/*.log" />
         </tarfileset>
    <tarfileset dir="${basedir}" preserveLeadingSlashes="true">
        <include name="*/.log" />
    </tarfileset>
    </tar>
</target>
```